# Grafana add Prometheus datasource, no access option

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Ok, so I'm not a devops guy.
I downloaded the latest image of grafana (6.6.0 atm).
Adding a prometheus data sources ended up with 502 Bad Gateway. What I've seen different than the tutorial is that there is no "Access" option anymore. Checking `http://localhost:3000/api/datasources/` I've seen that my data source has 'proxy' access by default.

[image]

Then I switched to an older version of grafana (6.4.0) which has the possibility to change access and everything went ok.
[image]
 Anyone knows how to select other access type in the newer versions of grafana? I checked their docs but everything seemed outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Prometheus datasource config editor was migrated to React (as part of this PR https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/20248) the Access select option was not included. There is also this open issue https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12757 that opened a discussion about dropping the support for the ES browser access (and potentially other data sources).

In the meantime, you could provision your datasource(s) using a config file (see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#example-datasource-config-file) and specify the proper value for the `access` key.

Other option is to use the REST endpoint and modify your datasource in a similar way (see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/data_source/#update-an-existing-data-source).